# Filtro no listview pega o item da posição errada

Tags: android, listview, intent

No Listview sem usar o filtro quando clica ele mostra os dados corretos na outra activity, mas quando filtra um item ele muda a posição e passa outro ID os dados não tem nada haver com o item que passa para a outra activity.

*Codigo do ADAPTER:*

```
public class AdapterListaDebitosPendentes extends BaseAdapter  implements Filterable{


    private List<DebitosPendentes> debitosPendentesList;

    private List<DebitosPendentes> debitosPendentesFiltrados;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Activity context;
    private ValueFilter valueFilter;



    public  AdapterListaDebitosPendentes(List<DebitosPendentes> debitosPendentesList, Activity context) {
        this.debitosPendentesList=debitosPendentesList;
        this.debitosPendentesFiltrados=debitosPendentesList;
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return debitosPendentesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(position).getId();
    }







    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DebitosPendentes debitosPendentes = debitosPendentesList.get(position);
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_debitos_pendentes,null);


            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_debitos_pendentes,null);
            TextView txtVencimentos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVencimento);
            TextView txtValores = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtValores);

          String[] valoresExploded = debitosPendentes.getVencimento().split("-");

            txtVencimentos.setText("Vencimento: "+ valoresExploded[2]+"/"+valoresExploded[1]+"/"+valoresExploded[0]);
            txtValores.setText("Valor: "+debitosPendentes.getValor()+ " Valor atualizado: " +debitosPendentes.getValorAtualizado());






            return convertView;

    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(valueFilter==null) {

            valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
        }

        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter  extends Filter{
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
                List<DebitosPendentes> filterDebitos = new ArrayList<DebitosPendentes>();

               for (int i=0; i<debitosPendentesFiltrados.size();i++){

                   if((debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(i).getVencimento().toUpperCase())
                           .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){

                       DebitosPendentes debitosPendentes = new DebitosPendentes();
                       debitosPendentes= debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(i);
                        filterDebitos.add(debitosPendentes);

                   }

                   if((debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(i).getValor().toUpperCase())
                           .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){

                       DebitosPendentes debitosPendentes = new DebitosPendentes();
                       debitosPendentes= debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(i);
                       filterDebitos.add(debitosPendentes);

                   }

                   if((debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(i).getValorAtualizado().toUpperCase())
                           .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())){

                       DebitosPendentes debitosPendentes = new DebitosPendentes();
                       debitosPendentes= debitosPendentesFiltrados.get(i);
                       filterDebitos.add(debitosPendentes);

                   }


               }

                results.count=filterDebitos.size();
                results.values=filterDebitos;

            }else{
                results.count=debitosPendentesFiltrados.size();
                results.values=debitosPendentesFiltrados;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
             debitosPendentesList = (List<DebitosPendentes>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

Activity onde uso o Adapter:

```
public class DebitosPendentesActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private ListView listDebitosPendentes;
    private ArrayAdapter<DebitosPendentes> arrayAdapter;
    public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    public DebitoPendentesDao debitoPendentesDao;
    public ItensDao itensDao;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private EditText edtPesquisa;
    AdapterListaDebitosPendentes adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_debitos_pendentes);
        try {

            databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(DebitosPendentesActivity.this);
            debitoPendentesDao= new DebitoPendentesDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());

            final List<DebitosPendentes>debitosPendentesList = debitoPendentesDao.queryForAll();

            listDebitosPendentes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDebitosPendentes);

           adapter=  new AdapterListaDebitosPendentes(debitosPendentesList, this);

            listDebitosPendentes.setAdapter(adapter);

            //searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

         listDebitosPendentes.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
           // setupSearchView();



            listDebitosPendentes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetalhesDebitosActivity.class);

                    //Passa para a activity o id no banco de dados
                    intent.putExtra("ID",id);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });



        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





     edtPesquisa= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPesquisa);


             edtPesquisa.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                 @Override
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                   //adapter.getFilter().filter(s);


                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     ///adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                 }
             });





    }

/*    private void setupSearchView() {
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

    }


    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            listDebitosPendentes.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            listDebitosPendentes.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Resolvi o problema, do adapter onde retorno o getItemId();
ficou assim :  return debitosPendentesList.get(position).getId();